# Commit file property changes to git repository

Tags: linux, git, filesystems

I have bunch of file with incorrect permissions: since the files may contain passwords I don't want them to be world-readable after checkout so that the user does not have to remember changing acces rights.

```
-rw----rw-.  1 beginner beginner 16 19. Sep 04:36 file1.config
-rw----rw-.  1 beginner beginner 16 19. Sep 04:36 file2.config
-rw----rw-.  1 beginner beginner 16 19. Sep 04:36 file3.config
```

But after using chmod to get

```
-rw-------.  1 beginner beginner 16 21. Sep 04:36 file1.config
-rw-------.  1 beginner beginner 16 21. Sep 04:36 file2.config
-rw-------.  1 beginner beginner 16 21. Sep 04:36 file3.config
```

git status does not show these files as changed.

Question: How can I commit property changes to these files to my git repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `filemode` is not on, thats why `git` doesn't show the changes.

Look into your project, in the .git folder for the config file and you should see something like this:

```
[core]
    filemode = false
```

set it to `true` or run following command

```
git config core.filemode true
```

You can find more examples for git configuration [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)